# How to load a new view onto the view stack when working with uitableviews

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, custom-cell

I currently have a Navigational project loaded with 4 custom cells that have a UItextField covering the whole cell. My goal is to create a method that will load a new view when the user "touch down" event calls my method that loads a new view onto the navigation stack.

the only problem being I dont know the exact code for this. here is what I have now but I have dozens of errors popping up

```
- (IBAction)newView{
    SelectionListDetailViewController *selection = [[SelectionListDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectionListDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:selection animated:YES];
}
```

I have 18 errors that say !stray '@' in program

am I on the right path? do you see anything that I am doing wrong? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want a new view when the User taps the UITextField of your tableView cell ?

Comment: Do you have SelectionLIstDetailViewController.h imported?

Comment: I want to to load when touchdown happens on UITextField, I have added that connection in, And yes I have imported SelectionList....h

Comment: Why there is "]" before bundle (after nib name)?

Comment: opps, typo.. its meant to have ...ViewController" bundle:nil]; I didnt use copy and paste sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. Try pushing the view controller while using

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

and use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:selection animated:YES];
```

Make sure you import the necessary header files  (SelectionListDetailViewController.h) & reference it to the right class.

Comment: Cool will give that a shot now.

Comment: Everything loads up find now.. however I'm not sure how I am meant to get that to load a new view.. Where dose it get called once the user touches the uitextfield?

Comment: Once the user touches into the UITextField, the control goes right into -(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField . Whatever code you put right after that will execute as soon as user touches textField.

Comment: This is my method, dose it look right or am I missing a call to the uitextfield.. I guess I have to check for which uitextfield to use it on aye?

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
 
 SelectionListDetailViewController *selectionDetailViewController = [[SelectionListDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectionListDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectionDetailViewController animated:YES];
}

Comment: Any textField (if touched) will run this method. Did you import header file properly ? Did you reference class in the beginning with @class ?

Comment: oh no I didnt refrence the class.. I thought you meant #import header when you said refrence the class.. will figure that out now.

Comment: thus far 

@Class myclassname in my header

then I have #imported myclass.h file


-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
 NSLog(@"inside class");
 if (manufactureText.touchInside) {
  NSLog(@"inside if");
 SelectionListDetailViewController *selectionDetailViewController = [[SelectionListDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SelectionListDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectionDetailViewController animated:YES];
 }
}

when I run the app and select the uitextfield Nothing happens, it dosnt even enter the method.

Comment: to get onto the chat part of the site I need 20 reputation points